# Chart.js - Tooltip hover issue

Tags: chart.js, angular-chart

I am facing a problem. I created an chart using the time scale, but when I hover the first chart value for example, it displays the first tooltip of with the first sries's value. See the following screenshot:

[image: diagram]

Comment: It's not clear from the image and yiur question what the problem is vs. what you were expecting.  Can you be more specific and add your chart.js config plus some sample data so I can recreate your chart?

Comment: I am using chart Js with Angular chart Js plugin http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

Is quite hard provide the data but I will try.

The graphic hover is using the data index as reference instead the real position on graphic. When I hover the first position of the blue/orange, it triggers the red and purple hover.

Comment: Thanks!  Just post whatever you are doing to display your graph in angular chart.js and that should be enough for me.  Based on what you said, It sounds like you might just want to use a different [tooltip interaction mode](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-tooltip-configuration).  I'm not sure where in Angular Chart.js you can configure this (but I do know you can), but you just need to tweak `tooltips.mode` and `tooltips.intersect` for the behavior you want.  Also remember that all datasets are displayed in each tooltip (not just the one you hovered over).

Comment: @LeonardoSalomão, you have to put here the code which originated this chart